# What should I do to install cordova without error?

Tags: powershell, cordova

I tried installing cordova but every time I try it there is an error

Error: Command failed: powershell (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).caption
'powershell' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

```
at makeError (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\windows-release\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at Function.module.exports.sync (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\windows-release\node_modules\execa\index.js:338:15)
at windowsRelease (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\windows-release\index.js:39:19)
at osName (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\os-name\index.js:39:18)
at new Insight (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\insight\lib\index.js:37:13)
at new RelentlessInsight (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\telemetry.js:31:1)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\telemetry.js:39:15)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32) {
```

code: 1,
stdout: '',
stderr: "'powershell' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\n" +
'operable program or batch file.\r\n',
failed: true,
signal: null,
cmd: 'powershell (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).caption',
timedOut: false
}

What should I do for this? Please give me suggestions.

Thankyou

Comment: install nodejs with an msi, then run in cmd: `npm install cordova`. Anddd Tada!

Comment: Thanks for thr suggestion but itd still the same. Should I install powershell ??

Comment: I actually realised I wrote a mistake on the above comment: I had forgotten the -g flag. I have then two solution: Uninstall the current version of cordova that you have now, then run in an Elevated Prompt (Cmd run as an Admin): `npm install cordova -g`. If it still doesn't work, then try using a Linux Subsystem (More complex). But give the first one a shot, it really should work.

Comment: If  you still get the same error, you can try installing a slightly older version that doesn't use the execa module: Cordova@9.0.0. You can try installing it by: `npm install cordova@9.0.0 -g`